# Spotify API Implicit Grant Flow Authentication Error after some time (401)

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, spotify, implicit-grant

I use the Implicit Grant flow to communicate with the Spotify API in an express project, but after some time it seems like my `access_token` is expired. But I've read that with Implicit Grant flow, the token wont expire? I tried getting a new one from the Api, when the old one expires, but this didn't work.

```js
(function () {

    var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

    function getHashParams() {
        var hashParams = {};
        var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
            q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        while (e = r.exec(q)) {
            hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
        }
        return hashParams;
    }

    function generateRandomString(length) {
        var text = '';
        var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }
        return text;
    };

    var userProfileSource = document.getElementById('user-profile-template').innerHTML,
        userProfileTemplate = Handlebars.compile(userProfileSource),
        userProfilePlaceholder = document.getElementById('user-profile');

    oauthSource = document.getElementById('oauth-template').innerHTML,
        oauthTemplate = Handlebars.compile(oauthSource),
        oauthPlaceholder = document.getElementById('oauth');

    var params = getHashParams();

    var access_token = params.access_token,
        state = params.state,
        storedState = localStorage.getItem(stateKey);
    if (access_token == "") {
        access_token = localStorage.getItem('spotifyAuthToken');
    }
    if (access_token && (state == null || state !== storedState)) {

    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(stateKey);
        if (access_token) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    userProfilePlaceholder.innerHTML = userProfileTemplate(response);

                    $('#login').hide();
                    $('#loggedin').show();
                }
            });
            localStorage.setItem('spotifyAuthToken', access_token);
        } else {
            $('#login').show();
            $('#loggedin').hide();
        }

        document.getElementById('login-button').addEventListener('click', getAccessToken, false);

        function getAccessToken() {
            var client_id = '7c35e3a74f364538866db979db4f35f1'; // Your client id
            var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3000'; // Your redirect uri

            var state = generateRandomString(16);

            localStorage.setItem(stateKey, state);
            var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state app-remote-control user-modify-playback-state user-read-currently-playing streaming';

            var url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
            url += '?response_type=token';
            url += '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(client_id);
            url += '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scope);
            url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri);
            url += '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state);

            window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
})();
```

In the console I get a 401 Error when making further http requests.

Comment: No, [it says](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/implicit-grant/#:~:text=Access%20tokens%20issued%20are%20short%2Dlived%20with%20no%20refresh%20token%20to%20extend%20them%20when%20they%20expire.): "Access tokens issued are short-lived with no refresh token to extend them when they expire." This means it can get an access token that expires in one hour, without the possibility to refresh the token.

Comment: And there is no workaround to get a new Token? Like reloading the website? Or do I have to use another auth flow then? Because on Mobile I could only get Implicit Grant to work and I need the API for long timeperiods